Extracting values from a raster file in QField
I am going to be taking samples from a boat (in Antarctica) and need to be able to quickly extract the water depth from a bathymetry raster file. Is there a way to do this this Qfield (IOS)? I have imported all the data into QField already and all looks fine (although I can't highlight the raster as the active layer). Any advice?
